# front-end bind same port 443 is conflicting in haproxy

Tags: http, haproxy

I am using below configuration  - Its seems both are conflicting. Any idea, how to resolve this. I want to make sure to run both service on same port i.e. 443

```
frontend www
bind x-x-x-x:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/abc.pem
mode http
acl if_string_nv path_beg /test_rum
acl if_string_nv1 path_beg /nv
use_backend nv_server if if_string_nv
use_backend nv_server if if_string_nv1

backend nv_server
       server server1 x-x-x-x:8090 

frontend haproxybackend_agent
  bind x-x-x-x:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/abc.pem
      mode http
    option forwardfor
    use_backend nfdb

frontend haproxybackendhttp_agent
      bind x-x-x-x:80
     option forwardfor
      use_backend nfdb
#
backend nfdb
       #balance roundrobin
       balance leastconn
      server node-2 x-x-x-x:9200 check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both binds is x-x-x-x the same IP? If so you will want to move them into the same frontend and have multiple certificates defined on a single bind line. Such as this:

```
  bind x-x-x-x:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/abc.pem crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/def.pem
```

Then use acl's to differentiate the traffic.

Otherwise, you will want to have it on different IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks @dcorbett - Yes it worked fine. All x.x.x.x having same internal IP address
Help please - In second fronted, i have to receive data in https and forward to back-end in http format to x.x.x.x:9200.

Any help? What code i should write where i will receive data in https format and store it in http format.

Comment: Using `mode http` in both the frontend & backend sections will automatically do this.